# /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found - Error deploying latest gatsby app to Amazon Amplify

Tags: node.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy a website I just built with React to Amplify but I keep getting this error:

```
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
```

This is the full message from amplify console:

```
2022-11-29T03:46:43.053Z [INFO]: Now using node v18.0.0 (npm v)
2022-11-29T03:46:43.080Z [INFO]: Installing default global packages from /root/.nvm/default-packages...
2022-11-29T03:46:43.080Z [INFO]: npm install -g --quiet yarn@1.22.0
2022-11-29T03:46:43.082Z [WARNING]: node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
                                    node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
2022-11-29T03:46:43.083Z [WARNING]: Failed installing default packages. Please check if your default-packages file or a package in it has problems!
2022-11-29T03:46:43.084Z [INFO]: # Executing command: yarn install
2022-11-29T03:46:43.115Z [WARNING]: node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
                                    node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
2022-11-29T03:46:43.115Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-11-29T03:46:43.116Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
```

I have trying specifying the version of Node I want to use because gatsby require above v18.0.0 so my package.json looks as follow:

```
"engines" : { 
    "node" : ">=18.0.0" //
  }
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

here is also my build settings:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - nvm install 18.12.1
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: public
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same error attempting to build a new application on AWS Amplify with GatsbyJS. I tried installing the missing dependency, `glibc-devel`. It is actually up-to-date per the core repositories but is still behind the proper release needed with this specific version of node.

I swapped over to the docker image for that version of node, and it worked just fine (specifically `node:18.12`). I left everything else default/auto-detected
[image: Screenshot of AWS Amplify build image settings showing node at version 18.12]

Comment: well i did not try that... at the end I downgrade the gatbsy version and it worked well